# How do I tell if computed gotos are supported?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm writing a bytecode interpreter that can either use computed gotos or a normal `switch` for the main instruction dispatching loop. The key bits are wrapped up in a couple of macros that can either be defined to use computed gotos or not.

I'd like to decide which mode to use by default based on whether or not the compiler supports computed gotos. Does anyone know how to determine that? As far as I can tell, they work on GCC and Clang, but I don't want to just hardcode a couple of random compiler names.

Comment: You can also achieve the same effect of eliminating bounds checking in MSVC by a "default: __assume(0);" statement, informing the compiler that it will never happen. I suspect there may be other ways of giving other compilers the same hint directly (GCC's __builtin_unreachable probably also works as an alternative here)

Comment: @doynax, it's not nearly the same effect. With computed gotos you can pre-fill an array with label addresses, for example, like in OCaml bytecode interpreter.

Comment: @SK-logic: You're right, they're doing threaded code and trading reduced indirection for size, I didn't think think of that. (Any idea idea what the Jumptbl_base offset on 64-bit systems is about? It seems code_t is always full pointer so they don't appear to be saving space by coding relative 16/32-bit code offsets.)

Comment: Scratch that, that's precisely what they're doing. The real question is whether I should be impressed or horrified.

Comment: @doynax, at least you should be impressed by their benchmark results. This approach pays well in terms of performance, and with a bit of preprocessor magic it does not even look that horrible. Although, the OP question still holds - there is no elegant way to detect if this extension is supported (I do not consider autoconf approach to be "elegant" in any reasonable way).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a tool such as [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/), the following feature test have been useful for me:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([if ${CC-gcc} supports computed gotos])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE(
  [AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
    [],
    [[
      void *my_label_ptr = &&my_label; /* GCC syntax */
      goto *my_label_ptr;
      return 1;
      my_label:
      return 0;
    ]])],
  [AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
   AC_DEFINE(HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTOS, 1,
     [Define to 1 if the compiler supports computed gotos])],
  [AC_MSG_RESULT(no)])
```

It will define the macro `HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTOS` if the compiler supports the GCC syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach, but I'm not using autoconf.